# a problem with Suzuki-Kasami mutex algorithm

Tags: distributed-systems, mutual-exclusion

I have some sort of a misunderstanding regarding the Suzuki-Kasami distributed mutex algorithm. I am writing my question here because I failed on gaining access to the original paper.

I will call processes sites for convenience.

**My question**

Why the token holder $j$ releases its token only when $RN_j[i]==LN[i]+1$ and not when $RN_j[i]>LN[j]$.

I mean, since we cannot assume anything on the quality of communication, maybe site $i$ had the time to increment his sequence number **twice** so that the token holder got a message with difference $2$ from $LN[j]$. In this case the token holder will not release his token and starvation will be applied.

Comment: Is $LN[i]$ a queue entry? Assuming its a queue entry, it expects next item in queue

Comment: @user3483902 No, $LN[i]$ indicates the last request number for which site $i$ successfully received the token.